# How to calculate a streak of results in mysql?

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I'm completely stuck with this one. I have my matches table,my roster tables and my players table. And I'm using a subquery to determine the result for each player in each match order by the match date.

This is the query:

```
SELECT day, nickname, IF(team=res, "win", IF(res="e", "draw", "lose")) as result from (SELECT p.day, j.nickname, r.team, p.res from 
rosters r join matches p on r.match = p.id 
join players j on r.player = j.id  
order by r.player desc, p.day desc) as t;
```

This gives me a list of day, player and result for all players and all matches they played in order. So for example:

| day | player | res |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | lose |
| 3 | mark | draw |
| 2 | mark | win |
| 1 | mark | win |
| 4 | richard | win |
| 3 | richard | draw |
| 2 | richard | win |
| 1 | richard | win |

So my expected outcome is to go through this list from bottom to top in order counting the times the result repeats until it changes, so it starts counting again with the new result, and so on.

I'm trying to get a table like this, which I can later select and sort to get highest winning streaks, losing streaks, streaks without wins, etc. for each player.

| player | result | streak |
| --- | --- | --- |
| richard | win | 2 |
| richard | draw | 1 |
| richard | win | 1 |
| mark | win | 2 |
| mark | draw | 1 |
| john | lose | 1 |

Does any idea come to mind? Maybe you have a better suggestion in the previous part before building my initial table?

Comment: have you thought about doing it server side in a language like PHP?

Comment: @imvain2 This is indeed my DB from a laravel practice I'm doing and I already have the app. I just thought it could easier to get some view on mysql to before coding it but It looks like I was wrong haha. I think I could do this with nested for loops but I was trying to achieve it on mysql

Answer (score 1):

With a gaps and islands problem like this, you can subtract the number of times a person has gotten the current result thus far from the number of all results for the person thus far to make a unique (per person/result) streak id.
Then it simply is a matter of grouping by that.

```
select nickname, result, count(*) as streak
from (
    select
        nickname,
        result,
        count(1) over (partition by nickname order by day) -
            count(1) over (partition by nickname, result order by day) streak_id
    from (

        -- your original query
        SELECT day, nickname, IF(team=res, "win", IF(res="e", "draw", "lose")) as result from (SELECT p.day, j.nickname, r.team, p.res from 
        rosters r join matches p on r.match = p.id 
        join players j on r.player = j.id  
        order by r.player desc, p.day desc) as t

    ) results
) results_with_streak_id
group by nickname, result, streak_id
```

[fiddle based on simplified data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2180e74c4b0ff980298221c0a9605fc8)

If you need to preserve order (within a person), also select day in the results_with_streak_id subquery and at the end order by nickname, min(day).